# Why won't my computer run Python programs that import from sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I write this simple little Python program to give me the prime factors of a number:

```
from sympy import primefactors
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("Prime factors", primefactors(number))
```

The program works when run within the Anaconda IDE but not outside of it - at least not on my computer. It runs perfectly on my wife's laptop and on my son's desktop without the need to launch Anaconda. They both run Window 10.

The same thing happens with any program headed `from sympy import *`. When I run the program in IDLE I get the error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'
```

Again, if I run the program on another computer I don't have this problem.

Does the problem lie my computer (i7-3770K, 16 GB RAM, Windows 10) or somewhere else?

Comment: What's the error that you're encountering?

Comment: without knowing more about your actual setup, we can only speculate. When you say "outside of your Anaconda IDE" I'll assume you mean from some terminal, in which case, it's fundamentally because the `sympy` library is not in your path. What does `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version)'` in the terminal give you?

Comment: Also, what does `python -c "import sys; print(*sys.path, sep='\n')"` give you?

Comment: python -c "import sys; print(*sys.path, sep='\n') gives  me C:\Users\mgrea\anaconda3\python37.zip
C:\Users\mgrea\anaconda3\DLLs
C:\Users\mgrea\anaconda3\lib
C:\Users\mgrea\anaconda3
C:\Users\mgrea\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\mgrea\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\mgrea\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\mgrea\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin

Comment: python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version)' returns Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined

Comment: When I run the program it closes immediately after starting. All I get is a blip on the screen.

Comment: What **exactly** are you doing? You really must be precise/specific. What does run the program mean? Are you invoking it directly in the CMD prompt? `python my_program.py`? Are you just double-clicking the `.py` in a window?

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I did. I had both python and anaconda on my computer, thinking that I needed to install python before anaconda. I deleted them both and then and reinstalled anaconda only. The problem programs now work as expected. Sorry if I've inconvenienced anyone.